# What's the difference between two set of codes, I know what arrow function does but why traditional expression does not work?

Tags: javascript, web

**What's the difference between two set of codes, I know what arrow function does but why traditional expression does not work?**

**Set - 1**

*loop through all elements*

```
    checkboxes.forEach( function (checkbox){
        console.log(checkbox);

        if( checkbox === this || checkbox === lastChecked)
        {
            inBetween = !inBetween;
            console.log(" start checking them inbetween");

        }

        if(inBetween)
        {
            checkbox.checked = true;
        }
    });
```

**Set - 2**

*loop through all elements*

```
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {

  console.log(checkbox);
  if (checkbox === this || checkbox === lastChecked) {
    inBetween = !inBetween;
    console.log('Starting to check them in between!');
  }

  if (inBetween) {
    checkbox.checked = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set - 1 is foreach with ES5 definition style whereas Set-2 is for ES6. Make sure the target/version supports ES5 so that Set-1 will work.

Also, you might wanna try replacing **this** with **self** in set-1 and defining  self as this before the foreach or use bind

```
  var self = this;
this.addNewObjects = function(arr){
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        self.addObject(new Obj(obj.prop1, obj.prop2));
    });
}
```

or

```
    this.addNewObjects = function(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        this.addObject(new Obj(obj.prop1, obj.prop2));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, **may be** u use `this` in scope of `forEach()` function, this is one of more different of two.
more explain is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Yeah I think that is the case as this is determined by how the function is called or gotta use the bind method along with it to set the value of function's this regardless of how it is called